# How can I predict on the trained SVR model and resolve error Value Error: X.shape[1] = 1 should be equal to 22

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have datasets that have more than 2000 rows and 23 columns including the `age` column. I have completed all of the processes for `SVR`. Now I want to predict the trained SVR model is where I need to input `X_test` to the model? Have faced an error that is

```
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 1 should be equal to 22, the number of features at training time
```

How may I resolve this problem? How may I write code for making predictions on the trained SVR model?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Make fake dataset
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data= np.random.rand(2000,22))
dataset['age'] = np.random.randint(2, size=2000)

# Separate the target from the other features
target = dataset['age']
data = dataset.drop('age', axis = 1)

X_train, y_train = data.loc[:1000], target.loc[:1000]

X_test,  y_test  = data.loc[1001], target.loc[1001] 

X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape((len(X_test), 1))
print(X_test.shape)

SupportVectorRefModel = SVR()
SupportVectorRefModel.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = SupportVectorRefModel.predict(X_test)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 1 should be equal to 22, the number of features at training time
```

Comment: How comes and this is a question identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61963748/how-to-make-prediction-on-the-trained-svr-model-where-i-need-to-input-x-test) (even with the incorrect number of `57` in the error message, before I edited it to the correct `22`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reshaping of `X_test` is not correct; it should be:

```
X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(1, -1)
print(X_test.shape)    
# (1, 22)
```

With that change, the rest of your code runs OK:

```
y_pred = SupportVectorRefModel.predict(X_test)
y_pred
# array([0.90156667])
```

**UPDATE**

In the case as you show it in your code, obviously `X_test` consists of one single sample, as defined here:

```
X_test,  y_test  = data.loc[1001], target.loc[1001]
```

But if (as I suspect) this is not what you actually want, but in fact you want the rest of your data as your test set, you should change the definition to:

```
X_test,  y_test  = data.loc[1001:], target.loc[1001:]
X_test.shape
# (999, 22)
```

and without any reshaping

```
y_pred = SupportVectorRefModel.predict(X_test)
y_pred.shape
# (999,)
```

i.e. a `y_pred` of 999 predictions.

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980987/how-to-generate-x-train-by-using-for-loop